# How are people dealing with ampersand replacement in CKEditor?

Tags: civimail, ckeditor

In WordPress and Civi 4.7.13, CKEditor replaces & with

```
&amp;
```

This inherently breaks using smarty in mail/PDF templates. How are other people getting around this one?

I've tried setting forceSimpleAmpersand in files/civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-config.js as per [the CKEditor docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config), but I can't get it to have any effect. Other settings in the same config file do work, so I know that file is ok.

This setting did work in the older version of CKEditor in 4.6.x, annoyingly.

Comment: We've verified that forceSimpleAmpersand is a bug, and filed an issue with CKEditor. Hopefully they'll fix soon. I don't have a good workaround for dealing with the issues this causes with smarty in mailing/PDF templates, though.